# Local path-connectedness and homeomorphisms.

Tags: general-topology

My question is:

> Does an homeomorphism preserve local path-connectedness?

I think that it must be true because the homeomorphisms let us say if two topological spaces are "equal", but I don't know how to prove it.

Thanks for everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **yes**.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be homeomorfic topological spaces, and let $h$ be an homeomorphism between the two. Let $X$ be locally path connected. Then for every $x \in X$, there is a (open) neighborhood $U_x$ such that for every $y, z \in U_x$, there is a path $\gamma : [0,1] \to X$ connecting $y$ to $z$:
$$
  \gamma(0)=y,\ \gamma(1)=z.
$$
Being an homeomorphism, $h$ maps open neighborhoods of $x$ to open neighborhoods of $h(x)$ (and viceversa!), hence if we consider $h\gamma$, this is a path (continuous because composition of continuous functions) connecting $h(y)$ to $h(z)$.

Recapping: taking any point in $Y$, there exists a neighborhood of its preimage which is locally path-connected. By transporting it to $Y$, we get a neighborhood in which every pair of points is linkable with a path which is the image of the path between the preimages of the pair chosen.